# Stretch axes in plotly 3D plot R

Tags: r, plotly, scatter3d

I have a 3D scatter plot (plot_ly) that has all the axes of the same length by default - different scale, of course. I want to stretch along one axis (x), is there a way to do this?

Sample code using `mtcars`:

```
> plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ wt, y = ~ disp, z = ~mpg, 
          type = "scatter3d", mode = "marker", opacity = 0.6)
```

I can zoom, or rotate the plot but I want the default x-axis to be twice as long as the y and z axes.

[image: default result]

Comment: Maybe `aspectratio` can do the trick? See the [plotly manual](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-scene-aspectmode).

Comment: Thanks! How/where do I add this? I've tried adding it to the main command without success. Having trouble finging proper poltly documentation, their website does not explain the basics of their package much.

Comment: Apparently `aspectratio` is not an attribute of a `scatter3d` plot. I'm not well versed in plotly either, but maybe using a layout can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

```
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ wt, y = ~ disp, z = ~mpg, 
        type = "scatter3d", mode = "marker", opacity = 0.6) %>% 
layout(scene = list(aspectmode = "manual", aspectratio = list(x=1, y=0.2, z=0.2)))
```

Just adjust the `aspectratio` as you wish.